# „… – und der ist(,) ich weiß nicht wie viele Jahre jünger(,) als ich.“

Tags: comma, parenthesis

Wenn ich einen Satz bilde, der da lautet

> Schau dir an, was der schon alles erreicht hat – und der ist(,) ich weiß nicht wie viele Jahre jünger(,) als ich.

, muss ich dann die Kommas setzen oder nicht? Oder sind diese vielleicht sogar optional?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das *und*, und alles was davor steht, kann man für die Analyse weglassen, der Teil dahinter ist ein vollständiger Hauptsatz:

> Der ist<sub>(1)</sub> ich weiß nicht wie viele Jahre<sub>(2)</sub> jünger<sub>(3)</sub> als ich.

Die Stellen, an denen man Kommas setzen könnte, habe ich markiert und durchnummeriert.

Wie sähe denn der Satz ohne den Einschub aus? Das wäre ja wohl dieser Satz:

> Der ist jünger als ich.

Das Wort *»jünger«* gehört also ganz offensichtlich zum umschließenden Satz und ist kein Teil des Einschubs. Tatsächlich ist *»jünger als ich«* eine adverbiale Bestimmung der Art und Weise (modales Adverbial), also ein zusammengehörendes Satzglied, in das auf gar keinen Fall ein Komma hineingepflanzt werden darf.

Die Position (3) scheidet also definitiv aus.

Wie sieht es mit (1) und (2) aus? Denn diese beiden Stellen markieren ja die Grenzen des Einschubs:

> Der ist – ich weiß nicht wie viele Jahre – jünger als ich.

Mit Gedankenstrichen, die hier übrigens hervorragend passen (wo sonst, wenn nicht hier?) ist die Sache ziemlich klar. Aber es geht ja um Kommas. Der Satz:

> Ich weiß nicht wie viele Jahre.

ist selbst ebenfalls ein vollständiger Hauptsatz, also ein eingeschobener Hauptsatz.

Der [Duden sagt dazu](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Komma-bei-eingeschobenen-Hauptsatzen):

> **Komma bei eingeschobenen Hauptsätzen**
>
> Eingeschobene Hauptsätze (Schaltsätze) werden normalerweise in Kommas eingeschlossen, etwa: *Man will Satzzeichen ja nicht, sagen wir, allein nach Lust und Laune verstreuen. Das Buch hieß, glaube ich, „Nieten in Nadelstreifen“. Hochmut, so heißt es, kommt vor dem Fall.*
>
> Allerdings deutet das „normalerweise“ schon darauf hin, dass es auch andere Fälle gibt. Einige floskelartige Ausdrücke werden nämlich offenbar gar nicht mehr als eingeschobene Sätze empfunden und daher oft auch nicht mehr in Kommas eingeschlossen: *'Ich habe ihn[,] wer weiß wie lange[,] nicht mehr gesehen. Sie bereitet sich[,] so gut es geht[,] auf die Prüfung vor. Die Vorsitzende ist ja[,] weiß Gott[,] keine Heilige. Er blieb[,] Gott sei Dank[,] unverletzt.*

Die vom Duden explizit erwähnte Floskel

> wer weiß wie lange

hat nach meinem Dafürhalten schon eine sehr große Ähnlichkeit mit

> ich weiß nicht wie viele Jahre

Daher könnte man dies mit etwas gutem Willen durchaus auch als kommabefreite Floskel durchgehen lassen. Dagegen spricht aber die Länge des Einschubs (6 Wörter, bzw. 8 Silben). Nachdem die Kommas aber auf jeden Fall erlaubt sind, würde ich hier auf Nummer Sicher gehen, und die Kommas an den Stellen (1) und (2) setzen. Also:

> Der ist, ich weiß nicht wie viele Jahre, jünger als ich.

Comment: Sehr schöne Analyse und Herleitung der Regel.

Comment: Gut argumentiert, da der Satz aber eher gesprochene Sprache abbildet ist _ichweißnichtwieviele_ m. E. wie ein einziges Wort zu betrachten – _20_ würde man ja an derselben Stelle verwenden. Beim Lesen entstehen durch die Kommas Unterbrechungen, die in dem gesprochenen Satz so definitiv nicht vorkommen. Ich würde sie daher weglassen.

Comment: @Raketenolli: wenn ich spreche, mache ich eine Kommapause nach *der ist* und leite damit den Einschub ein, der zum Abschluß natürlich wieder ein Komma braucht.

Answer (score 2):

Das ist eine interessante Frage.

Ich konsultiere hierzu hoffnungfroh das schönste Werk, das der deutsche Markt zur Zeichensetzung bereithält: Ch. Stang, A. Steinhauer: Duden Handbuch Zeichensetzung, 2. Auflage 2014. Dieses Buch widmet 140 lehrreiche und unterhaltsame Seiten alleine dem Komma.

Bemerkenswerterweise finde ich den hier angesprochenen Fall (der aber für die deutsche Sprache gar nicht so untypisch ist, siehe weitere Beispiele unten) dort nicht verzeichnet, oder jedenfalls nicht beim schnellen Durchblättern.

Geht man systematisch vor, passt am ehesten noch das Kapitel "Das Komma bei Zusätzen", wo man liest:

> Zusätze unterbrechen den Fluss des Satzes und werden deshalb durch Kommas vom Rest des Satzes abgehoben. Es gibt jedoch auch Fälle, in denen die Kommasetzung freigestellt ist. [S. 55]

Es folgen zahlreiche Beispiele wie

> Ihre Erfolge, z.B. als Aida, sind unvergesslich.
>
> Wir planen für nächste Woche, das heißt vielleicht auch für übernächste, einen Gegenbesuch
>
> Bei einem Durchschnitt kleiner als 2,5 findet keine Wertung statt.

(Diese Beispiele hier nur um kurz anzudeuten, in welchem Bereich wir uns befinden. Sie sind im Buch in verschiedenen Unterkategorien schön erläutert.)

All dies hilft nicht direkt im Falle des *ich weiß nicht wie viele Jahre jüngeren* Gegenübers. Ich würde jedoch nach der Lektüre des Kapitels (auf der Suche nach möglicherweise passenden Beispielen) sagen, man sollte es am besten so schreiben:

> Schau Dir an, was der alles schon erreicht hat - und der ist ich weiß nicht wie viele Jahre jünger als ich.

Grund: Dies ist ganz offenbar ein niedergeschriebenes Stück gesprochener Sprache. In der gesprochenen Sprache würde der Satz glatt durchgesprochen, ohne einen Hiatus nach "ist". Setzte man ein Komma, wäre der Leser provoziert, auch ein kleines Päuslein einzulegen, was aber eben dem natürlichen Sprachfluß dieser Wendung widerspräche. Also besser ohne Komma.

**Alternativen**

Allerdings gebe ich zu, dass man beim Lesen dann auch leicht ins Stolpern kommt. Je nach Geschmack bietet sich also vielleicht an, den Einschub durch Gedankenstriche zu markieren:

> Schau Dir an, was der alles schon erreicht hat! Und der ist - ich weiß nicht wie viele - Jahre jünger als ich.

Womit das lesetechnische Problem gelöst ist. Doch handelt man sich damit neue Sorgen ein: Das "ich weiß nicht wie viele" ist ja eigentlich eine Mengenangabe, die nicht einfach aus dem Hauptsatz herausgelassen werden kann, ohne ihn zu verstümmeln. Am Ende ist die kommalose Schreibung also doch besser.

Eine weitere Alternative schlägt Kommentator Thorsten Dittmar vor:

> Und der ist, ich weiß nicht wie viele Jahre, jünger als ich.

Der Hauptsatz wäre dann mit "Und der ist jünger als ich" nach wie vor wohlgeformt. Diese Lösung funktioniert in diesem Fall. Sie funktioniert allerdings nicht mit anderen Fällen solcher Wendungen:

**Ähnliche Wendungen**

> Der hat schon **Gott weiß was** erlebt. Jetzt ist er aber im Ruhestand.
>
> Gestern habe ich **du glaubst nicht was für** ein schönes Pferd gesehen!
>
> Lisa hat die Nacht über **weiß der Teufel was** getrieben.
>
> Mein Schlüsselbund ist **weiß der Kuckuck wo** abgeblieben.

Eine Schreibung "Der hat schon, Gott weiß was, erlebt" schließt sich hier aus, da der Hauptsatz "Der hat schon erlebt" nicht mehr wohlgeformt wäre.

Comment: Ich würde da keine Kommas setzen, auch wenn das nicht gesprochene Sprache wäre. Kann das aber nicht begründen.

Comment: Wenn man jedoch "Jahre" in dein Einschub mit reinnimmt, dann würde der Haupsatz zu *Und der ist jünger als ich*. Der optionale Einschub wäre dann *ich weiß nicht wieviele Jahre*. Ich würde daher schreiben *Und der ist, ich weiß nicht wieviele Jahre, jünger als ich*.

Comment: Dir scheint völlig entgangen zu sein, dass das Wort *»jünger«* gar nicht zum Einschub gehört.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast  Welche Rolle spielt das für die Frage, ob man hier besser Kommas setzt oder nicht? - Allerdings gebe ich Dir vollkommen Recht, die ganze Frage bei "Kommas bei eingeschobenen Hauptsätzen" anzusiedeln.